# What happens when you create a git branch and then remove the previous commit?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I created a new file (with quite a bit of code and hard work) and committed it to the master branch of my git repo. A moment later I realized that I probably should've created a branch for the file. I thought I could revoke the commit from master and commit again on a branch, but I think I did things in a silly order. For some reason I created the branch first, then went to revoke the commit, using [is it possible to revoke commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434152/is-it-possible-to-revoke-commits) as a guide.

Here's essentially what I did:

```
echo "Lots of code and hard work" > newfile.txt
git commit -m "thoughtless commit" newfile.txt
# Oh wait, I should've branched!
git branch thoughtful
git checkout thoughtful
# Hmm, I didn't mean for that last commit to be in master
git checkout master
# get the previous commit's hash
oldhead=$(git log | awk 'BEGIN{commitcount=0; } /^commit/{ if (commitcount++ == 1) { print $2 }; }')
git reset --hard "$oldhead"
git checkout thoughtful
```

So now I've apparently trashed a commit on *master* (indeed, 'newfile.txt' no longer exists on *master*), but it still exists in *thoughtful* (and I guess reflog).

Would someone be so kind as to explain what I did here, and why no commit on *thoughtful* is required?

Comment: For future reference, your `reset` command can be abbreviated to `git reset --hard HEAD^` without needing `oldhead`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created your branch `thoughtful`, it started from the current state of `master`, which already contained the commit. From that point onwards, the two branches are unrelated. Whatever you do to `master`, it won't affect `thoughtful`. The commit that introduces the file will still be part of `thoughtful` regardless.

You should try `git log thoughtful` and `git log master` to review the history of commits. On `thoughtful` you'll still see the commit you tried to remove from master.

#### A more complete breakdown follows

Assuming we're currently on `master`...

```
echo "Lots of code and hard work" > newfile.txt
git commit -m "thoughtless commit" newfile.txt
```

You've created a commit on `master`, containing `newfile.txt`.

```
# Oh wait, I should've branched!
git branch thoughtful
```

You've created a branch `thoughtful`, which is at the current state `master`, but is otherwise *completely unrelated to master*. The branch's starting point is `master`, because you didn't explicitly specify a starting point and `master` is currently checked out.

```
git checkout thoughtful
```

Now you're on `thoughtful`; you don't have to `checkout` new branches to make them real, this step has absolutely no effect since you do the following:

```
# Hmm, I didn't mean for that last commit to be in master
git checkout master
```

Now you're on `master`.

```
# get the previous commit's hash
oldhead=$(git log | awk 'BEGIN{commitcount=0; } /^commit/{ if (commitcount++ == 1) { print $2 }; }')
```

You've jumped through a *ton* of hoops to get the previous commit, when you could have just used `master~` or `HEAD~`. *That* is how you get the "previous" commit, not by inspecting `git log`. In the future, to undo the last commit, please use `git reset --hard HEAD~`.

```
git reset --hard "$oldhead"
```

You've changed the commit `master` points to. Now it's whatever commit the above command discovered, presumably the commit before `newfile.txt` was introduced. Using `--hard` causes Git to update the working directory as well, so `newfile.txt` goes away; had you omitted `--hard`, `newfile.txt` would still be in the directory, but listed as a new file in `git status`.

```
git checkout thoughtful
```

You've gone back to `thoughtful`, which contains `newfile.txt`, updating your working directory and reintroducing `newfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The basis to understanding this is that you have to visualize **branches as pointers** to a commit which is the HEAD of the branch. And every commit points to one or more of its parents. A branch ( master etc.) is a pointer. No more, no less.

When you created `thoughtful`, you created another pointer to the same commit as master. Then you moved the master pointer to the previous commit. You are not removing a commit or something like that, you moved the master pointer to the previous commit. And your `thoughtful` branch / pointer is still pointing to the commit you want. You are in the state you wanted to be in!

PS: To get old HEAD, use `git reflog` or ref names like `HEAD@{1}`. Also, in this case, a `HEAD~` would give you the right one as well.

Comment: OK, but I thought of *tags* as pointers to a commit. Is the difference between tags and branches merely semantic?

Comment: @kojiro - Yeah semantic and what they can point to is different, but pointers nonetheless - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tag-and-a-branch-in-git

Comment: [git book on tags](http://book.git-scm.com/3_git_tag.html) says that a tag is `basically a branch that never moves`. It's easiest to think that your commits hold the entire state of all the files on disk at that commit point, and tags/branches are pointers to those commits.